# different type of python dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to python, I have created a script where expected outputs should be able to get user that has *globalRole = Admin* and user with *tprojectRole = Admin*. I am getting the values in the json file which it is a dictionary. How can I get my expected values below after my example no. 3?
Thanks

Below are examples of JSON file that I'm parsing.

```
"firstName": "User",
"lastName": "Last",
"emailAddress": "user.last@g.com",
"locale": "en_GB",
"isActive": "1",
"defaultTestprojectID": "",
"globalRole": {
    "name": "admin",
    "rights": [
        {
            "name": "testplan_execute",
            "dbID": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "testplan_create_build",
            "dbID": "2"
        },
    ],
    "dbID": "10"
},
"globalRoleID": "10",
"tprojectRoles": "",
```

This is the other example of JSON file where *tprojectRoles* has value but *globalRole* is not an admin.

```
"firstName": "User2",
    "lastName": "Last2",
    "emailAddress": "user2.last2@g.com",
    "locale": "en_GB",
    "isActive": "1",
    "defaultTestprojectID": "",
    "globalRole": {
        "name": "viewer",
        "rights": [
            {
                "name": "testplan_execute",
                "dbID": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "testplan_create_build",
                "dbID": "2"
            },
        ],
        "dbID": "10"
    },
    "globalRoleID": "10",
    "tprojectRoles": {
    "1456505": {
        "name": "admin",
    }
```

Example no. 3, if both global role and projectrole is Admin it should display both.

```
"firstName": "User3",
    "lastName": "Last3",
    "emailAddress": "user3.last3@g.com",
    "locale": "en_GB",
    "isActive": "1",
    "defaultTestprojectID": "",
    "globalRole": {
        "name": "admin",
        "rights": [
            {
                "name": "testplan_execute",
                "dbID": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "testplan_create_build",
                "dbID": "2"
            },
        ],
        "dbID": "10"
    },
    "globalRoleID": "10",
    "tprojectRoles": {
    "1456505": {
        "name": "admin",
    }
```

Now, How to get this expected values?

```
    User Last GlobalRole: Admin
    User2 Last2 GlobalRole: Viewer ProjectRole: Admin
    User3 Last3 GlobalRole: Admin ProjectRole: Admin
```

This is my script the I'm working on:

```
for admin in tls.getUserByID(loginID): #getUserByID API
            firstName = admin.get('firstName')
            lastName = admin.get('lastName')
            globalRole = admin.get('globalRole')
            projectRole = admin.get('tprojectRoles')
            user_active = ('Active')
            user_inactive = ('Inactive')
    if str(globalRole['name']) == "admin" or str(projectRole) == "":
        print(loginID, loginName, firstName, str(globalRole['name']))                   
    else:
        for projKey,projRole in projectRole.items():
            if "admin" in str(projRole['name']):
                print(loginID, loginName, firstName, str(globalRole['name']), projKey, projRole['name'])
```

Comment: @alexpdev I change some statements, thanks for correcting.

Comment: @alexpdev I've added my for loop that has api call to get users

Comment: @alexpdev yes as you can see my expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to extract the data from the `projectRoles` field.

```
for admin in admins:
    text = admin["firstName"] + " " + admin["lastName"] + " GlobalRole: "
    grole = admin["globalRole"]["name"]
    if grole == "admin":
        if not admin["tprojectRoles"]:
            print(text + grole)
            continue
    prole = list(admin["tprojectRoles"].items())[0][1]["name"]
    print(text + grole + " ProjectRole: " + prole)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working, however results are not the expected outputs .

Comment: Yes, to be able to print `User Last GlobalRole: Admin` , `User2 Last2 GlobalRole: Viewer ProjectRole: Admin` and `User3 Last3 GlobalRole: Admin ProjectRole: Admin`

Comment: @ckmb  try it now

Comment: it now works thanks for your response I'll just edit some functions in my code